# Ionic iOS app not displaying or playing local mp4 file

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ionic-framework, html5-video

I have an Ionic app where I want to display a video playing in the background. For Android, I am using the Jaeger25 HTMLVideo plugin which is working fine, but I also need this working on iOS, but it just will not play the video. The video iteself lives in the www/img folder and for iOS my video tag looks like this:

`<video src="img/main.mp4" webkit-playsinline="" loop preload="" type="video/mp4" ng-if="!androidPlatform"></video>`

When i try to debug it using the Safari Web Inspector, it says it cannot find the img/main.mp4 file. However, as a test i also tried to display an `<img>` from the www/img folder using the following tag:

`<img src="img/main.png" alt="" />`

And the image is displayed correctly, so i know the src path is correct.

The encoding of the mp4 is correct too as i can put the file in my DropBox and display it on my iPhone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick test I was able to get a video player with controls working on both android and ios with just the use of regular html5 video tags:
    
    `<video controls>
      <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>`

And the video file is at `www/video/video.mp4`. I got a test .mp4 file from [here](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4).

edit:
Cordova version: 5.4.1
Ionic framework version: 1.2.1
Ionic CLI version: 1.7.12

Comment: Is this through an Ionic app?

Comment: yes, I tested it inside an Ionic app that I did ```ionic build ios / android``` and installed into the device.